# unable to set response after create hook

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-hook

I am unable to set response after create 
hook.result.thumbnail = res._id

the process is like following:

- I am using "fs" model to upload video.
- After upload I am creating thumbnail by using "ThumbnailGenerator" model in hook :after create.
- In this I make another entry in "mongodb" for thumbnail, after insertion I take the id of that and patch in "mongodb" of video file.
- And then set the "hook.result.thumbanil = res._id,"

but this is not working

Comment: We really need to see your code to be able to assist.

Comment: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1181#issuecomment-457275186

Comment: By code I mean https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve